# Inserir várias colunas e tabelas em uma variável no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Estou em um dilema simples (creio eu)
Eu possuo 3 tabelas em questão.. a tabela Associado e a tabela Pedido e a caixaEnt.
Os campos do associado são:
id, ref_by, nome ....
Os campos do pedido são: 
pedido_id, pedido_cliente, pedido_data, pedido_status, pedido_total_produto.
Os campos do caixaEnt são:
id, id_cliente,cliente,id_doc,valor,data

O que preciso fazer é o seguinte:
Preciso inserir na tabela caixaEnt, todos os pedidos que tenham o status 4. Porém preciso que preencha com os dados: id_cliente, cliente (nome dele), id_doc(código do pedido), valor (valor do pedido), data (data do pedido).

Alguém que tenha entendido meu dilema pode me ajudar? Ahh.. lembrando que é tudo no mysql direto.

Comment: E quais são as chaves primárias e estrangeiras de suas tabelas?

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é a sua dúvida

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um select unindo as tabelas de associados e pedidos e utilizar o resultado para adiconar na tabela CaixaEnt.

De acordo com a estrutura que você mostrou, a query ficaria assim:

```html
insert into caixaEnt(id_cliente,cliente,id_doc,valor,data)
select a.id, a.nome, b.pedido_id, b.pedido_total_produto, b.pedido_data from associado as a inner join pedido as b ON a.id = b.pedido.cliente WHERE b.pedido_status = 4
```

Aqui tem um tutorial com outros exemplos:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/